# Projective Texture Mapping

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to project a image as a spotlight from my light source.

So far, my fragment shader looks like

```
uniform sampler2D image;
varying vec4 projCoord;

void main() {

gl_FragColor = texture2DProj(image, gl_TexCoord[0].xyzw);


}
```

And my Vertex Shader looks like

```
varying vec4 projCoord;
void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    vec4 pos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    projCoord = gl_TextureMatrix[4] * pos;
}
```

I just want to project a image from my light source. I know I need to add 
my light vector and manipulate it that way, but I can't project my image correctly. Atm, my
image is projected onto the object loaded (a cube) on all four sides.

Comment: Are those your actual shaders (I don't think so, because using `gl_TexCoord[0]` instead of `projCoord` and performing two times the same transformation, and forgetting to do the projection transformation is probably all not intended)?

Comment: Unfortunately those are, I am at the point where I have revised it so many times I can't find the original where I use projCoord.